# jquery tooltip negative position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use a jquery tooltips, but the hovering div is placed at negative coordinates(-27000,-27000)

The element which should have the tooltip is this:

`<span style="float:right;font-weight:bold" title="I am tooltip">U</span>`

I initialize the tooltip with this call:
            `$(function(){
                $('[title]').tooltip();
            });`

The jQuery tooltip is properly initialized, because on mouseover, I get a new div, but placed at huge negative coordinates:

```
<div id="ui-tooltip-4" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-widget-content" 
role="tooltip" style="top: -27712.3px; left: -27517.2px; display: block;">
    <div class="ui-tooltip-content">I am tooltip</div>
</div>
```

What can be the cause of bad placement? 
These are the styles being applied on the span with the title:

```
float: right;
font-weight: bold;    
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
border-collapse: collapse;
font-size: 0.85em;
line-height: 1.3;
list-style: none outside none;
color: #222222;
```

libraries used:

```
jquery-1.8.3.min.js
jquery-ui-1.10.10.min.js(and jquery-ui-1.10.10.css)
```

Thanks for any ideas what's causing the bad positioning of tooltip

Comment: Can you replicate this with a jsFiddle?

Comment: It's going to be difficult to say without more context.

Comment: In jsFiddle everything is fine. What more context should I add? I have no idea what could produce such behavior. I was hoping for some ideas because I'm trying to figure it out for half a day.

Comment: If jsFiddle is fine, then the problem is surely somewhere else that you haven't provided information about...

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I don't know what other informations I should provide. The span element is nice and visible, all the styles coming from CSS which applies to the span are there. So what else could be the problem? I thought the jquery places the tooltip based on that span element. Please let me know what information should I add

Comment: The problem was in the qtip library which was loaded together with jquery-ui. Removing this library solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was importing [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/%20qtip%5C) library together with jquery-ui. After removing this library, everything is fine.