# jQuery UI tooltips generating positioning of -27000px

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I'm using jQuery UI tooltips on a dynamic WordPress site with Gravity Forms to create tooltips for checkboxes. I've managed to pull in all the dynamic info using standard jQuery and got everything working, including the tooltips. The only issue now is that the tooltips positioning (both x and y) are something like -27000px. Are there any positioning caveats that could be causing this or is it something else?

You can take a look here: http://dev2.roimedia.co.za/roimedia/contact-us/request-a-quote/

un: client
pw: demo

I've found this similar question on Stack Overflow - [jquery tooltip negative position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926561/jquery-tooltip-negative-position) but I don't have another tooltip library running.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I've searched your code and it doesn't look like you are using any `.tooltip()` methods (which is what are used in jQuery UI).  Also, there is a console error which reads "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined " Click `F12` using Google Chrome on your page to see the error.

Comment: @user1477388 Thanks for the comment. That method is called externally in this line - `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev2.roimedia.co.za/roimedia/wp-content/themes/roimedia/js/tooltip.init.js?ver=1.0"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. I see my jQuery file is empty which is weird.

Also, I see qTip is being called as with the similar question. This was worked on by other devs before me. Thanks. Closing.

Comment: Voting to close then. (Not sure if you have enough rep to remove you own questions.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario this is true :)