# jQuery UI tooltip positioning issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a positioning issue with jQuery UI's tooltips. I would prefer to not use jQuery UI, but the project I'm working on already uses it throughout and it's been requested I try and make use of it, rather than integrating my preferred option, qTip2.

When the tooltip appears, it causes a vertical scrollbar. I am positioning the tooltip centrally above the target and it's as I want it, excluding this issue.

```
$(function() {
$( document ).tooltip({
show: false,
    hide: false,
  position: {
    my: "center bottom-20",
    at: "center top",
    using: function( position, feedback ) {
      $( this ).css( position );
      $( "<div>" )
        .addClass( "arrow" )
        .addClass( feedback.vertical )
        .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
        .appendTo( this );
    }
  }
 });
});
```

I can see that the tooltip is being positioned at top:-600px which I assume is what is causing the scrollbar to appear.

I've tried changing / removing the positioning of the tooltip, but it didn't have any effect. I have tried removing parts of the CSS to pinpoint the problem and it seems related to the padding (any) or height (min, max or fixed).

Although removing padding and height fixes the issue, it obviously leaves the tooltip looking a bit ... Skinny. I would like to work out what the problem is and a way around it, so I can style the tooltip.

My current CSS (including the height and padding which I can see causes the issue) is as follows (there are also styles set for the arrows, which I've omitted as I can see they're not causing any problems):

```
.ui-tooltip {
    z-index:10;
    width:150px;
    padding:10px;
    min-height:20px;
    max-width:100%;
    font-size:0.875em;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color:#707070;
    background:#fffdc2 url(../img/fade.png) repeat-x;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid #e1e0aa;}
```

I know jQuery UI have [an open issue about connectors](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip), so I've tested it without any positioning settings and it made no difference to this.

I have seen [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926561/jquery-tooltip-negative-position) mentioned a few times, but it wasn't relevant as I do not have qTip, or anything else included.

I've set up a [JS fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MSLYw/).

I'd appreciate any help or advice.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see any scrollbar appearing ???

Comment: @ExpertSystem On the JS fiddle, there isn't no as the other page elements are missing. I wanted to demonstrate how I had it set up but in answer to your comment I started to add the rest of my mark up in (have taken it out, as the page is responsive it changes to fit in the JS Fiddle window and thus you won't be able to see my issue). I can see that the scrollbar only appears when there is almost enough content on the page to warrant one ... The extra height or padding pushes it over the edge. Annoyingly this makes the scroll bar flash on and off.

Comment: @ExpertSystem I have resolved this issue by setting the position to absolute.

Comment: LOL - great minds meet !

Comment: @ExpertSystem Haha yes! Thank you for your help, I picked your answer as you certainly helped me work this out. One of those where you've been looking at it for too long and can't see the obvious. Thanks again :)

Comment: I am not sure how I helped you, but as always I am glad to help :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you describe as the problem, the vertical scrollbar is added because an extra `div` ("#ui-tooltip-XX") is appended to the document's body with `position: relative`, which takes up extra space increasing the body's `scrollHeight` property (and causing the scrollbar to appear).
If this is "compatible" with the rest of your HTML (which I don't have in my disposal to test), you can circumvent this issue by setting the tooltip's `position` attribute to `absolute` (which does not contribute to its container's overall height.

```
// Add this in your CSS
.ui-tooltip, .arrow:after {
    position: absolute;
    ....
```

(Based on the rest of the HTML on your page, additonal modifications might be necessary.)

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wyhQN/)**.

Comment: I am facing similar problem, I want 
<code>using: function (obj, info) {

                        //if top side add class tooltip_top and remove class tooltip_bottom, then visa virsa
                        var tooltipBottom = (info.vertical </code>

info.vertical should be 'top' but I am getting 'bottom'. It was working fine in older version of jquery and jquery-ui. Now I have updated to latest versions.

Answer (score 2):

For my app (which has tooltips in cells in a jQuery DataTable within nested jQuery Tabs), just setting 'position: absolute' wasn't enough - I also had to give the tooltips an initial onscreen top and left position as it only gets positioned after creation:

```
.ui-tooltip 
{ 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100px; left: 100px;
}
```